# What meaning has the derivative of the Discriminant of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, discriminant

Let me ask it differently:

**1st example:**

I have the polynomial
$$p(x)=x^4 - \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{16} + 8} \, x^3 + r\,x^2 + r\sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{16}+8} \, x - 2r^3$$
which has 4 roots, three of which are $>0$. The graph of the three positive roots as a function of $r>0$ for fixed $\epsilon$ has 2 disconnected parts. In the case $\epsilon=0$ it becomes degenerate i.e. the 2 disconnected parts meet at $r=1$. For $\epsilon>0$ there is one larger branch and the two lower branches build together 1 connceted graph. Likewise for $\epsilon<0$ the 2 larger branches build together 1 connected graph, while the lowest branch stays separated. Therefore the point $\epsilon=0,r=1$ is a bifurcation point.

Now my question is, if it is coincidence that this bifurcation point $\epsilon=0,r=1$ is precisely the point where not only the discriminant $D(\epsilon,r)$ of $p(x)$ vanishes, but also the derivative with respect to $r$
$$D(\epsilon,1)={\frac {\epsilon\, \left( \epsilon-16 \right) ^{2}}{1024}}\\
\partial_r D(\epsilon,1) = {\frac {\epsilon\, \left( 3\,{\epsilon}^{2}-1184\,\epsilon-18688 \right) }{1024}} \, .$$

**2nd example:**
The polynomial is $$p(x)=x^3+2rx^2+rx+\epsilon$$ and its discriminant + derivative is $$D(\epsilon,r)=-32\,\epsilon\,{r}^{3}+4\,{r}^{4}+36\,\epsilon\,{r}^{2}-4\,{r}^{3}-27\,{\epsilon}^{2} \\ \partial_r D(\epsilon,r)=-96\,\epsilon\,{r}^{2}+16\,{r}^{3}+72\,\epsilon\,r-12\,{r}^{2} \, .$$ The graph of the three solutions degenerates (connected branches change) at $\epsilon=0, r=0$ and as it can be seen the discriminant and its derivative vanish at this point.

Coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

Your $p_3(x;\alpha)$ could vary with respect to $\alpha$ in such a way that two roots coincide but not the third, e.g. $p_3(x;\alpha)=x^3-2\alpha x^2+\alpha^2$.  Then $D=0$ identically but of course the only time when three roots coalesce is at $\alpha=0$ which is invisible to $D$.

Or you could have $p_3(x;\alpha)=(x-\alpha)^2(x-\alpha-1)=x^3-(3\alpha+1)x^2+(3\alpha^2+2\alpha)x-\alpha^2(\alpha+1)$, then again $D$ is identically 0 but you never get all three roots coalesce.

You need to go back to, e.g., $p,p',p''$ all share a root.

Comment: Do you have an example where $D$ does not vanish identially? If $p$ would depend on another parameter $\beta$ this case is rather specific.

Comment: Easy tweak: follow it for a small interval and deviate away either side.

Comment: Not sure what you mean! Besides so is there a meaning for the solutions if the derivative of the Dsicriminant vanishes with respect to a paramter? Like Branches are switching?

Comment: I think the question was not very well asked; needed to modify it.